# Query that JOINs 2 models ON

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5, and have 2 models `location` and `chauffeur` with the relations

`public function chauffeurs() { return $this->hasMany('App\Chauffeur'); }`

and

`public function location() { return $this->hasOne('App\Location', 'id', 'location_id'); }`

This is the query i have, that works

```
"SELECT *, 
                    (6371 * acos(cos(radians(".$latitude.")) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(".$longitude.")) + sin(radians(" . $latitude.")) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
                    FROM `locations` AS l
                    JOIN `chauffeurs` AS c
                    ON (l.id = c.location_id)
                    HAVING distance < c.radius
                    ORDER BY distance ";
```

This is what i have so far

```
Chauffeur::select('*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(1.492659)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(103.7413591)) + sin(radians(1.492659)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance ')
    ->join('Location', '`location`.`id`', '=', '`chauffeur`.`location_id`')
    ->havingRaw('distance < `chauffeur`.`radius`')
    ->get();
```

and am getting this error

```
`Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`492659)) * sin(radians(latitude))))` as `distance ` from `locations` inner joi'`
```

How would I use laravel models to make the same query? Any idea what i'm doing wrong or if there is a better way? Thanks

Comment: Don't use that surrounding backquote on your table name and column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DB::raw();with select query